# JSON Parser returning null for fieldname

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I have the following code and when I run it with a valid JSON,it returns null for fieldname.
I have been scratching my head over this for hours now.

```
    JsonFactory jFactory=new JsonFactory();
    JsonParser parser=jFactory.createJsonParser(bytes);

    while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
        String field_name=parser.getCurrentName();
        System.out.println("fieldName: "+field_name);
        parser.nextToken();
        if(field_name.equals("value")){
            System.out.println("value found");
            data=parser.getBinaryValue();
            out.write(new String(data));
        }//if
    }//while
    parser.close();
```

JSON sample:

```
      {
     "mimetype" : "text/plain",
     "value" : "c2FzCg=="
      }
```

Comment: please post a JSON sample you are using. Additionally you are executing two time `parser.nextToken()`

Comment: The second nextToken() call is for getting the fieldvalue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need a `nextToken` before the while structure, in order to skip the `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`.

Like this:

```
parser.nextToken();
while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
```